# Default DropDown and Checkbox List values

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have an 'add project' form which allows the person adding new project details to the db to select a project manager from a dropdown list and a team using a checkbox list. Project details are written to the Project table {ProjectID, CompanyID, ProjectName, StartDate, EndDate, Description}, ONE iteration is specified and written to the Iterations table (a project can consist of one or more iterations) {ProjectIterationID, ProjectID, StartDate, EndDate}. Members from the MEMBERS table become ProjectIterationMembers {ProjectIterationMemberID, ProjectIterationID, MemberID}.

What I am working on at the moment is the PROJECT DETAILS form which allows the admin to **add new project iterations**.

What I am trying to do is to set the name of the project manager previously chosen when adding the project by default in the dropdown and have the checkboxes checked by default - the ones that were selected when assigning team members to the project. How can I do that? Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Depending on how your app is organized, Session or ViewState may be appropriate. Are you familiar with them?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you pass through the name of the project manager (or better still, the id) and the list of team members then I think all you do is write:

```
ManagerDropDownList.value = IdValuePassedToForm;

for (var i = 0; i < TeamCheckBoxes.length; i++)
{
    if (TeamMembersPassedToForm.Contains(TeamCheckBoxes[i].value))
    {
        TeamCheckBoxes[i].checked = true;
    }
}
```